# DllNotFoundException: InterceptFeaturePlugin assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)

Tags: unity-game-engine, openxr

Working on a Unity 2021.3.11f1 OpenXR VR project with another person, where we're using Git for source control. I've pulled main and am trying to run a scene, but am getting the following error:

```
DllNotFoundException: InterceptFeaturePlugin assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.Samples.InterceptFeature.InterceptCreateSessionFeature.HookGetInstanceProcAddr (System.IntPtr func) (at Assets/Samples/OpenXR Plugin/1.4.2/Intercept Feature/InterceptCreateSessionFeature.cs:47)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.Features.OpenXRFeature.HookGetInstanceProcAddr () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/Features/OpenXRFeature.cs:676)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase.InitializeInternal () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:225)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase.Initialize () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:183)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:AttemptInitializeXRSDKOnLoad() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRGeneralSettings.cs:148)
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be? It's working on their side and I was able to run everything before I pulled main.

Comment: one of your referenced DLLs are missing

Comment: try reloading the `com.unity.xr.management` package

Comment: look at line 47 in file `Assets/Samples/OpenXR Plugin/1.4.2/Intercept Feature/InterceptCreateSessionFeature.cs` and see which assembly the script is trying to load, then find it and then re-reference that DLL again

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen How do I reload the ```com.unity.xr.management``` package? And this is line 47 in InterceptCreateSessionFeature.cs: ```return intercept_xrCreateSession_xrGetInstanceProcAddr(func);```. How could I re-reference that DLL? Sorry I'm new to Unity and all this.

Comment: look at the package manager tab

Comment: remove that package, and then reinstall/enable it

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Removed the package, but then instead of giving me the option to re-install it said "update to 4.2.1", so I chose that. So I think I've reinstalled the package but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: vist [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/dllnotfoundexception-unityopenxr-when-trying-to-run-deviceless-on-mac.1233226/) official report of the same issue

Comment: MacOS is not supported for Playmode and Standalone build. of XR

Comment: [github issue report](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/unity-xr-plugin/issues/15)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I'm doing this all from Windows and my partner is also doing everything from Windows. I'm not getting those errors seen in the solution for that official report and the github issues solution isn't referring to the same stuff I'm running into I think. But earlier you mentioned something about re-referencing a DLL?